# Personalizar el Popup que se genera en el layer:entity-field de gvNIX

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-roo, gvnix

Me gustaría saber como personalizar el siguiente `popup` que se levanta en  el **`<layer:entity-field>`** encontre la funcion **`fnPrepareInfo`** dentro del `layer` pero no sé si esa seria la función que estoy necesitando y tampoco sé como se utiliza, si me podrían ayudar. Quisiera mostrar solo algunos campos de mi entidad como por ejemplo: `Codigo - Nombre - Latitud -Longitud`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que necesitas agregar un poco mas de detalles ya que tu pregunta no es muy clara.

Comment: Disculpa, si. Al permitir mostrar y filtrar todos los campos geográficos como capas en el geoportal con el comando **web mvc geo entity all --class ~.web.MapController** el agrega la función  **showinfo = true** por defecto en el tag **<layer:entity-field>** dentro de show.jspx del mapa generado. Ésta función permite ver toda la información de la entidad tal y como se muestra en la imagen adjuntada. Quiero saber como editar esa informacion que se encuentra dentro de forma que solo se vea El Codigo, el nombre, la latitud y longitud de la Estacion registrada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vas por buen camino ;-).

Para personalizar la información de la capa necesitas definir en el fichero *.jspx* del mapa una función:

```
<script>

    function myLayerInfo(oMap,
            sLayerId, sEntityPath, sGeoFieldName, sFeaturePKValue,
            oFeature, oFeatureLayer, bSelected) {

           return "<div> EL HTML que quieras mostrar</div>";

    }

</script>
```

y en el tag de la capa añadir la propiedad:

```
 <layer:entity-field ... fnPrepareInfo="myLayerInfo"/>
```

Como ejemplo puedes ver la función que se utiliza por defecto para generar el popup en [leaflet.ext.gvnix.map.js función createLayerInfoString](https://github.com/DISID/gvnix-samples/blob/master/quickstart-geo-app/src/main/webapp/scripts/leaflet/leaflet.ext.gvnix.map.js#L7399)

¡Suerte!

Comment: Buenas @jmvivo Queria comentarte que probe lo que me habias dicho y nada, le dimos muchas vueltas, probamos crear la funcion dentro del java script **leaflet.ext.gvnix.map.js** inclusive y aun asi la propiedad **fnPrepareInfo** no respondia, hasta que encontramos que lo que hace es que siempre que **fnPrepareInfo** es nulo llama a la funcion "createLayerInfoString" ignorando siempre la funcion que cree y donde la cree. * if (!fnPrepareInfo) { fnPrepareInfo =
        * U.createLayerInfoString; } aun pasandole parametros éste siempre queda nulo.

Comment: Hola @marty-ayala hemos mirado y parece que el problema es un error en el fichero _leaflet.ext.gvnix.map.js_ en el momento de inicializar esa variable: se está usando `fnPreparInfo` en vez de `fnPrepareInfo`. Este bug estará resuelto para la versión final de gvNIX 1.5.1. Para solucionarlo en tu aplicación modifica todas las cadenas `fnPreparInfo` por `fnPrepareInfo` en el fichero _leaflet.ext.gvnix.map.js_. Disculpa las molestias y gracias.

Comment: Excelente, hice lo que me indicaste y ahora si funciono perfecto .. Muchas gracias.